# Access private data of other apps with root on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, root

I'm trying to use [libsu](https://github.com/topjohnwu/libsu) to be able to programmatically access the shared_prefs folder of an app not made by me, but for some reason, the folders are invisible even though adb shell, termux and MiXplorer all manage to see them properly when rooted

At first I've tried doing `SuFile.open("/data/data/com.package/shared_prefs").exists()`, but that always returns false, after that I tried these 2 ways

```
val out = Shell.cmd("ls /data/data/").exec().out.joinToString("\n")
Log.d(null, out)
```

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c ls /data/data").also { 
    it.waitFor()
    Log.d(null, String(it.inputStream.readBytes()))
}
```

And for both, it only listed 2 apps - mine and `com.google.android.gms`.

I know it's possible to access data of other apps because all apps mentioned above manage to do it, but how can I do it? Preferrably without remounting or messing up the permissions.

I've tried looking at other similar questions, but most are either unanswered, the solution either doesn't work in my case, or is just not what I need.

Edit: to clarify - yes, the app does have root access, and all the code above is wrapped inside `Shell.getShell {...}`, which prepares the root shell

Answer (score 1):

For anyone in the future facing this problem...I know it's a late response, but I was having this same exact issue and felt like I tried EVERYTHING until I came upon [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/245735/cannot-list-all-folders-in-data-data-in-few-apps) page.

**TL;DR:** It has to do with the namespace settings in Magisk. Go to your Magisk settings and find **Mount Namespace Mode** and change it to **Global Namespace**. Reboot and you should now be able to see all of the directories within your app's shell command :)